# Variants on gmail ids

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

First off all, I am a long way past high school and college and have spent the last 25 years writing Cobol. but I hope I can get an answer that I can comprehend :-)
This was something that occurred to me recently. If you have a gmail id, you implicitly have many ids since any variants with periods in them are still delivered to you.
So if your id is abc@gmail.com, then mail sent to
ab.c
a.bc
a.b.c
will all reach you.
How do I find out how many variants are possible for an id that is n-characters long?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. First of all, this is cool - I didn’t know this worked. However, does `a..bc` still work? What are the constraints?

Comment: You also implicitly have `abc+anythingyoulike@gmail.com`, which gives a lot more possibilities.

Comment: @BenjaminWang I don't think it likes consecutive full stops.

Comment: So then the number of variants is $2^{n-1}$ if you consider the $n-1$ gaps in between the letters? However, if the original address already has full stops, then it’ll be annoying to calculate.

Comment: Coming to think about it, even if it already have full stops, it won't be that hard to calculate: Suppose you have 'abc.def', then just pretend 'c.d' is one letter (say, 'x'), and solve for the case 'abxef'. If you want a proper mathematical answer, you should define your constraints more carefully and systematically

Comment: @BenjaminWang- I am happy enough with the $ 2^{n-1}$ answer. Don't want to muddy the waters too much. Thank you for indulging my curiosity!